# How to construct a CDF if you don't have the data but you know the slope and 50% point?

Tags: r, cdf

I have a question regarding the CDF function. In a study, the researchers fitted a CDF of the normal distribution on their data and presented the median (= -8.4 dB) and the slope (=18.7). How can I recreate this function (in R) so I can find out what percentage (y-axis) is expected for e.g. 9 dB on the x-axis? When I look at the formula of the CDF, I'm not sure where to insert the slope and median statistics...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need additional hypotheses on the distribution in order to recreate the full CDF function. Unless you have counter-arguments (from the data interpretation), let's assume it is normally distributed.

By definition, the derivative (slope) of a CDF function is its PDF function. Thus what you are given is the median and the PDF value at the median. For the normal distribution:

- the median (50% point) equals the mean
- PDF(mu) is `1/sqrt(2*pi*sd)`, where mu is the mean and sd is the standard deviation

Thus, with the additional hypothesis that the sought distribution is normal, its CDF will be the normal CDF (`pnorm` in R) with parameters:

- `mean = midpoint`
- `sd = 1/(2*pi * slope^2)`

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (checkmark in the left margin) if your problem is solved :-)

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for the reply! However the mu is not mentioned in that function and the result of it is a dot and not a function..?

Comment: Well as I had already mentioned you need additional hypothesis of normality for the problem to be well-defined. Thus the CDF is fully specified by its 2 parameters.

Comment: And mu is defined in my answer: the mean